# Backbone events not delegated to new element after setElement

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm implementing a Backbone view with an Underscore template. The view el is replaced with the template html using the setElement-function. The declaration of the function says that "...move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one" but for some reason this doesn't work. Any ideas why this isn't working as described on Backbone declaration?

Here's an example of the situation (relevant parts of the view):

```
     initialize: function(args) {
        _.extend(this, args);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
     },

     events: {
        'click .active-area': '_test'
     },

     _test: function() {
        // After "setElement" this doesn't fire anymore.
        this.model.set('color', 'green');
     },

     render: function() {
        // After this the "click" listener no longer exists.
        this.setElement(this.template(this.model.toJSON());

        return this;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.template(...)` isn't an element in the DOM.

In your code, `setElement` removes the event listeners from the old element, then delegates them to the new element, *which only exist in memory*, not on the page.

You should simply change the content of the current element instead.

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

---

> I need to replace the whole element html with the template html and that's why I need to use the `setElement` function.

Say you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="currentView"><!-- view's root (el) -->
    <button type="button" class="active-area">Click me</button>
    <span class="color"><%= color %></span>
</div>
```

Add a wrapping div and move the `#currentView` div into the template.

```
<div class="wrapper"><!-- view's root (el) -->
    <div id="currentView">
        <button type="button" class="active-area">Click me</button>
        <span class="color"><%= color %></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now `this.$el.html` will swap the whole element.

---

In the situation where you really want a view to swap its own root element, you can create a new element, then use jQuery's [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to put the new element in place of the old.

```
render: function() {
    // create a new element from the template
    var $newEl = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    // completely replace the current element in the DOM
    this.$el.replaceWith($newEl);

    // then tell the view
    this.setElement($newEl);

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Good point! Actually this solution isn't working in my case. I need to replace the whole element html with the template html and that's why I need to use the setElement function.

Comment: @QD make a wrapping element in your page, and move this element root into the template.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fully following. Can you give me more explanation on how this would work?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! I still think that this is not what I'm going after. In my situation the view element is part of the template and hence I can't use wrapper elements. The reason why I'm using templates here is that I'm rendering a bunch of views using the same template. If I understand correctly, in your solution the same wrapper would be overwritten and only one element rendered.

Comment: @QD Your question should include a [mcve] of what you're describing in the comments. Unfortunately, I can't guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my question and especially the comments haven't been the clearest. It seems that your solution works, in my case, if I move the wrapper completely separate from the template. That way it only works as a base element for the view. If I put it inside the template, it gets overwritten and only the last element is rendered.

Comment: Works just fine without the wrapper. Backbone view generates a div as a default el and the solution just replaces it. setElement-function only re-delegates the event listeners to the new dom element. Thanks to Emile Bergeron for the solution!